# Bootstrap 3 - Different grid sizes with different alignments

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 3 and my site has 2 cols. The left content is left align and the right content is right align. On smaller display I will work with 1 col. So the right col is under the left col. That works fine.

But I want that on smaller displays both cols have left alignment. Is this possible?

Here my current code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
      content a
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xm-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
      content b
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Text is aligned to the left by default, so you can use a media query to align text to the right when your screen is larger than 992px (col-sm max width). it will then default back to the left when the screen is less than 992px

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  #right-col{
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      content a
   </div>
   <div id="right-col" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      content b
   </div>
</div>
```